# Layout TableView with navigation bar and tool bar

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode5

I placed TableView on a middle of a layout with constraints to stay aligned with top/bottom guide bars and left/right sides.

When I insert prototype cell it doesn't go to the top and it's the same at run time. Seems like TableView holds space on top for something?

How do I make first cell to appear on top?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your storyboard, `adjust scroll view insets` of your view controller is selected by default.

[image]

The best way to solve this problem is to add top and bottom constrains between the table view and its super view, instead of the layout guide, because the view controller will adjust the insects of the table view automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default, iOS adds a content inset on the UITableView. There are two solutions. You could either set the layout constraints to the top and bottom of the view instead of the top and bottom layout guides, or you could click on the view controller and in the attributes inspector, disable Extend Edges for Under Top Bars and Under Bottom Bars.